# Catching 2 different xmlhttp.responseText in one time

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

How would I catch 2 responses (in echo) from my Php with xmlhttp.responseText?

My php sends this back:

```
echo "error1";
echo "error2";
```

Now I need to catch these 2 echos and basicly 'split' them so I can do this for example

```
document.getElementById("errorDIV").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

document.getElementById("ERROR2DIV").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText2;
```

So errorDIV becomes the text "error1" and ERROR2DIV becomes the text "error2".

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should modify the output of your PHP script so that it includes a delimiter, eg.:

```
echo "error1";
echo " || ";
echo "error2";
```

Now on the client side you can split the responsetext into a javascript array:

```
var responseArray = xmlhttp.responseText.split("||");
document.getElementById("errorDIV").innerHTML=responseArray[0];
document.getElementById("ERROR2DIV").innerHTML=responseArray[1];
```

There are cleaner ways, you might want to learn how to output JSON in PHP and how to use the output in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is only 1 response from your server. You could however wrap the server response in a format the client can 'read', like xml or more preferable json.

From xml/json/eg, you are actually receiving an object with multiple values. From there you can assign the different values to different dom-elements.